# Linux linking folders

Tags: linux

I have two folders /tmp/logs and /home/tmp/

/tmp/logs has 50 files already in it. 
I want to move all the files to /home/tmp and also when a new file is created in /tmp/logs it gets created to /home/tmp instead.
So /tmp/logs just exist as a folder but nothing gets created inside it.

Comment: So you want to create a symbolic link?

Comment: When I create ln -s src dest, and create a file in src it gives src is out of space. I want that file to be created in dest instead eventhough I tell the file to be created in src.

Comment: Fix the program(s) that are creating the files in `/tmp/logs`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#move /tmp/logs to their new location
mv /tmp/logs /home/tmp    

#replace the original /tmp/logs with a link to /home/tmp
ln -s /home/tmp /tmp/logs
```

Now whenever a program requests the kernel that anything be done in `/tmp/logs`, the kernel will see it's a symbolic link and will instead act on the corresponding file in `/home/tmp` (what the link points to).